# Does the semidirect product $(H⋊K)$ is the smallest group contained the groups $H$ and $K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semidirect-product

I recently learn from the semidirect product lesson, and I occur a problem that if given the $2$ arbitrary groups $H$ and $K$, and we also construct the semidirect product group $(G=H⋊K)$ from permutation representation, I wonder that  whether the $G$ is the smallest order contain the two groups $H$ and $K$ ?  Since I "guess" there are lots of approaches to create the group from $H$ and $K$, thus the smallest must be important to us.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No. What if $G=H{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$? If the orders are coprime then the direct product is minimal.

Comment: $H\times K$ is the set of pairs $(a,b)$ with coordinate-wise multiplication.

Comment: There is certainly always a group of the smallest order containing the two groups as subgroups. Just check all groups of order $\le |H||K|$. There are only finitely many groups to check.

Comment: thank you very much, you definitely let me learn many things

Comment: If you have no objections about the answer you can accept it.

Comment: sorry, I think last night for a long time that what is the mean of G=H, is that (H⋊K)⋊K? if so, can you tell me why it is not,and the proof of the if (|H|,|K|)=1, then the H⋊K>HxK

Comment: If $G=H$ then the smallest group containing $G, H$ is $G$. 


A semidirect product cannot properly contain the direct product because these two products contain the same number of elements.